# setting default value from settings for ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have my app reading from default preferences that I have set up. The four options that the user may select are "none, dog, cat, bird". These preferences are then dealt with in methods such as -(NSDictionary *)intialDefaults and -(void)setValuesFromPreferences.
I want the option "None" to be selected by default when the app is installed for the first time. As of now, nothing is selected by default when the app, the user must go into settings and choose one.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you in advance and I apologize if this is extremely obvious

Comment: is four options in uitableview or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you store preferences in NSUSerDefaults, you can use

[objectForKey: method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/objectForKey%3a)

and if it returns nil, you can assume that the option selected is None, and update your model.